# Corrupt normal baking output in Blender 3.6

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

Ever since Blender 3.5 (and now in 3.6) I get corrupt outputs when baking from a high poly to a low poly model. Edit: I have now tried this in 3.6.1 with the same result. At this point I have to assume this is some form of bug. The issue persists even when saving in 3.6 and baking out - but loading the .blend file into 3.4 causes no issues.

Blender 3.6:

[image: 3.6 Bake]

Ignore the artefacts around the mouth in the 3.6 image and eyes, that's a result of the low-poly mesh topology and ray casting, I've just painted them out manually in the 3.4 image. The issue is most obvious in the normal map, but the name problems appear with diffuse and AO baking, too.

After some messing about I determined that Blender is putting in hard seams where the UV map is not sufficiently representative of the low poly mesh topology. So, basically, where you might crush part of the UV (such as the neck or parts of the nose here) Blender refuses to accept that and bakes as though it's dealing with separate UV islands.

You can see the problem most clearly in the underside of the nose. Not only are there hard lines, but the parts of the nostril don't actually line up. I'm working on an existing head for TES4: Oblivion and I can confirm the 3.4 baked normal maps work in-game exactly as expected, no issues.

Also, bear in mind because I have to bake to an existing in-game head that's animated I can't alter the low-poly model's UV at all without breaking everything in a way that's not easy to fix.

Blender 3.4:

[image: 3.4 Bake]

Comment: So, for clarity's sake - the image at the top of the post was baked with Blender 3.4.1 and is currently being used in-game with no issues. The image at the bottom was baked from the same .blend file loaded into 3.6.

Comment: What are your settings? Specifically, what are your Cage distances? It looks like the normal map in 3.6 is intensified, somehow. It's also quite a new version, so it could indeed be a bug. Is there any reason you want/need to use 3.6?